# Is it possible to get types in a dynamic array

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, generics, types

I have the following code, where I can add anything into an array. Is it possible to get correctly typed paramteres inside the `construct`'s anonymous function?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-fl5sn0?file=/index.ts)

```
const wrapper = <T>() => {
  const arr: T[] = [];

  const construct = (func: (...arr: T[]) => void) => {
    func(...arr);
  };
  const add = (x: T) => {
    arr.push(x);

    return { add, construct };
  };

  return { add };
};

const w = wrapper();

w.add(1)
  .add("2")
  .add({ a: 1 })
  .construct(
    // i need these to be correctly typed based on the types in add above  
    (a, b, c) => {
    //do something
  });
```

So far I just tried to used generict types, but doesnt seem to be working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gets you 90% of the way:

```
function wrapper<T extends any[]>(x: [...T]) {
  return {
    add<T2>(y: T2) {
      return wrapper([ ...x, y ])
    },
    run(f: (...x: T) => void) {
      f(...x);
    }
  };
}

const w = wrapper([]);

w
  .add(1)
  .add("2")
  .add({ a: 1 })
  .run(
    (a, b, c) => { }
  );
```

- `wrapper` now takes any array-like argument (`T extends any[]`) and spreads it in to a tuple (`[...T]`)
- `add` combines that tuple with any new value of `T2`. It creates a new wrapper in which `T` now refers to `[ ...T, T2 ]`.
- `run` (or `construct` in your example) requires a function of signature `(...x: T)`, which means that the current tuple type is spread across individual arguments.

If you run it in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8AKojgB5Q5gAmAzoumAJ4DaAugHwAUpAXIswDohhVgEpEAbwBQiRKhxQQqJNNmz0VKkQBMXRn0LbxqtbPmLlKDNjydmiIQNIAaRI0RiZagL7OvZ8E5gPk5HXkRCcQBedkQANzgYKmN-NWBQoVJRAG5U7y9vXPypCAQaKBREKKssXFQ7MVypZC8BDSpOAEZRVvbOACJtfp7ZNs1OCXo+TsRvEYdUQNTOdFcAI1cIaNjJ-NkcqUPDoA) you can see the correct signature for your `(a, b, c) => void` function:

[image: Screenshot of the TypeScript playground showing a correct function signature.]

The only thing I had trouble with was to allow `wrapper` to be constructed without any arguments. I guess you could change wrapper to not take arguments and then have an internal `_wrapper` for any following calls, but here's probably a better way.